# Pytest not detecting FizzBuzzTest.py

Tags: python, tdd, pytest

This is my code in FizzBuzzTest.py

```
import pytest
# content of test_sample.py
def fizzBuzz(value):
    return value

def test_returns1With1PassedIn():
    assert fizzBuzz(1) == 1
```

When I run  `pytest -v` in the command line

```
================================= 1 passed in 0.05 seconds ===================================================================

PS C:\Users\pytest\FizzBuzz_Kata> pytest -v

======================================== test session starts ================================================================================================

platform win32 -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0 -- c:\users\a606143\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe

cachedir: .pytest_cache

rootdir: C:\Users\pytest\FizzBuzz_Kata

collected 0 items
```

Could somebody please explain why pytest is not able to detect this file and run tests?

Comment: The file `FizzBuzzTest.py` will not be collected by default; either rename it so it starts with the `test_` prefix (e.g. `test_FizzBuzzTest.py`), or pass the file name explicitly (e.g. `pytest FizzBuzzTest.py`), or redefine test discovery in config (e.g. `python_files = *Test.py` in `pytest.ini`, see [Changing naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fiddled a little around and I seem to have found a solution, a little odd but it is working.

To have pytest to detect the file, it needs to be name with *test_* infront of the filename, so your file should be named: *test_FizzBussTest.py* <strike>and your function which pytest have to execute needs to have that exact same name, so your function needs to be named as such:</strike>

```
def test_FizzBussTest():
```

*Edit: After further researched, the function doesnt need to be named exactly as the file, it just needs to have `test_` infront of the function name so fx `test_sum():`*

Comment: Shouldn't `pytest` detect *any* function which starts with `test_`?

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#run-multiple-tests) it says the following:

`pytest will run all files of the form test_*.py or *_test.py in the current directory and its subdirectories.`

So the files have also to be named accordingly, but yes, same goes for the functions.